# In which Christian denomination(s), do people plan their weddings around the bride's menstrual periods?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, marriage, women, menstruation

I am a Russian Orthodox Christian, and I know other Russian Orthodox Christians who consider a woman's menses to be impure. As a woman, this monthly bleeding is not saying that I am evil or bad during that time. I am simply not pure. [Here](http://orthodoxinfo.com/praxis/menses.aspx) is a good explanation of this.

However, I know we Orthodox Christians plan our weddings around the bride's menstruation cycle, because she should be completely pure at that time.

Do other Christian denominations do this too?

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not a woman or a confidant of women, I've never heard this spoken of before in Protestant circles. That doesn't mean it doesn't happen, but I don't think this is a typical consideration.

Assigning (religious) impurity to menses would require adherence to the Law of Moses, I think. As a personal matter, there's nothing to prohibit someone from concluding that about herself, but since such a link between impurity and menstruation is ever made in the New Testament, I suspect that most protestants won't ever say that the two are inherently linked.

Answer (score 1):

For Protestant Christians this probably isn't much of an issue these days because they are accepting of contraception and the pill allows you to delay your period.

I'm not aware of how it was before the pill became available, and Christians of the past would usually speak about sex even less than they do now. But western (or Anglo at least) wedding conventions have long said that invitations must go out a long time before the wedding. Wedding venues usually also need to be booked many months in advance. Some women's cycles are very regular, but many aren't, so they'd have to just choose a date and hope for the best. Those unlucky couples who had their wedding during the wife's period would have to decide if they wanted to wait or go ahead and have sex anyway. The decision however would probably be on the basis of personal feelings of ickyness rather than ritual purity, a concept which isn't featured in Protestantism.

Answer (score -4):

Most protestant traditions don't focus on religious purity at all, let alone menstruation. First, Gentile Christians aren't required to follow Mosaic law. (Acts 15) Second, because of Grace and Christ's sacrifice, our sins and impurities are cleansed. There's nothing we can do to make ourselves more pure and that includes waiting a couple of days for your cycle to end.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).  While I agree with every statement you've made, this doesn't actually answer the question - there are usually outliers on any given practice.  This question is seeking to identify the outliers so that the counter case can be made on its own terms.

Comment: Take out the last sentence "There's nothing we can do to make ourselves more pure..." which is plain silly, and I'll upvote this. Keep the hyper-Augustinianism/hyper-Calvinism out of it. The answer that we don't have to follow the ceremonial aspects of the Law of Moses is the full answer. No need to introduce this silly anti-santification monergism nonsense.

Comment: @davidbrainerd Christianity.SE is a place to POLITELY ask and answer questions about the various Christian traditions. You have no right to call anyone's beliefs silly. Please learn to comment politely or go away.

Comment: "There's nothing we can do to make ourselves more pure" - The concept of ritual purity is gone. But as far as moral purity, this is total nonsense: "Pursue peace with all people, and holiness, without which no one will see the Lord:" (Hebrews 12:14) Nothing we can do to be more pure? That's what Satan wants you preaching, and you're following his will quite well.